# Windows is automatically adding a decimal point after 0

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-insider

For some reason Windows has started to automatically add a decimal point whenever I type 0 -- also if I type a after a space . it adds a 0 after it.

```
0.
 .0
```

This happens in almost every application (Notepad, Visual Studio, Chrome)  -- It does not happen in Skype for Business.

This just started within the past few days. Running Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 15025.rs_prerelease.17027-1750

Has anyone ever heard of this and know how to turn it off?

Comment: I had thought I had this fixed by pressing Windows+Space (Switch input language and keyboard layout) - but it still happens.  Weird is that it does not happen here (comment box), but does if I type in the New Answer box.

Comment: Verify you regional settings are correct.  You should also report this problem using the feedback application.

Comment: If I determine it is related to Windows 10 insider and not something I did wrong or an issue with my computer I will issue feedback.  The regional settings are correct.